# What is the fastest way to find divisor of any bigInteger in c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, biginteger, factorization

I want to run something like below code so that i would be able to find a divisor for numbers of ~30-40 length without having to check millions of possibilities even up to their square root.
What is the fastest possible solution to find a legitimate non trivial divisor of a number or how can i improve below code to run faster, without having to loop through all possible options.

```
    static int divisor(string numberToCheck)
    {
        BigInteger n = BigInteger.Parse(numberToCheck);
        BigInteger sqrt = Sqrt(n);
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return 2;
        for (UInt64 = 3; i <= sqrt; i+=2)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: How about having a list of the first x prime numbers. Try to evenly divide by any item of the list. If match found, break. If not start your algorithm at maxPrime + 1. Possibly updating the prime list as you go along to help with checking multiple numbers.

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you *have* all primes up to the quare root, checking would be the fastest (at least to my theoretical knowledge) and you would not have to switch to your algorithm at all. But maybe the list cannot even hold that many items, or the time to precalculate all the primes isn't worth it. You might need to play around with it until if fits your needs.

Comment: would you be a bit more elaborative?
first I'll have to find prime number up to x using some technique like sieve of Eratosthenes. Where x will be precisely equal to what?

Comment: @corak,it is completely useless advice for numbers in question

Comment: Again, you probably have to play around with it a bit. But for example, here is a list of [the first 10000 prime numbers](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - really, how so?

Comment: The reasoning is, the current algorithm is checking if the number is divisible by `3`, then `5`, then `7`, then `9`. But if the number would be divisible by `9`, then it would also be divisible by `3`. So the check for `9` is not needed. Only checks with prime numbers are needed. But then there is the tradeoff of knowing all the prime numbers vs. having an algorithm that works for all numbers. That's why I suggested to test against as many prime numbers as possible and then switch to the algorithm if one "runs out", starting with maxKnownPrim + 2 (because +1 would be an even number).

Comment: If I'm totally wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @Corak the number of primes that is smaller that a 40 digit number is approximately  `1.0857362047581295E+38` `( double x = 1e+40; var pi = x / Math.Log(x); ) ` See:  https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html It can take `3.4428469202122322E+24` years with 1M checks per second.

Comment: @Eser Yes it would take a long time to generate the list of prime but by that same token it will take a even longer to find find the divisor of a big number if every odd number is tested.  And up to square root if a smaller number.

Comment: @SaifUllah - just curious, why do you think `n%2` is a special case?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can skip testing even numbers

Comment: @Eser - Okay, that *does* seem to put a dent into that plan. Stupid reality, always messing with theory. :)

Comment: @Eser Exactly.  It was not practical even is primes was free.  Primes help but not enough.  You inferred that calculating primes it what broke it.

Comment: **[Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)**

Answer (score 1):

For numbers of 30 to 40 digits, you need a better algorithm than trial division, which has time complexity O(sqrt(*n*)).

In the mid 1970s, John Pollard invented two algorithms that are small increases in complexity but large increases in power: the rho algorithm and the *p*-1 algorithm. Both algorithms are O(sqrt(sqrt(*n*))), and neither is particularly hard to program.

If those algorithms don't work, the next step is to try the elliptic curve method, invented by Hendrik Lenstra in the early 1980s. You will have to work harder to get a decent implementation, but you will be able to find factors up to 30 or 40 digits without too much trouble, and you will certainly be able to split a 40-digit composite.

Google for all those algorithms, or search here on Stack Exchange, or ask specific questions if you don't find what you need. You might also look at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com), which has implementations of all those algorithms.

Comment: Sorry, But other than some introduction text, I don't see any code, any useful link etc.

Comment: @Eser: This is not a trivial question that can be simply answered in an SO answer. So user448810 does the next best: he informs about the algorithms to look for. I am pretty sure that there is no need to do a LMGTFY. If personally find this answer very useful. Much better than the "answer" that tells the orginal poster that it is more or less useless and impossible and which nevertheless got two upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Factorization of large numbers is hard. So hard that it's the basis for a lot of modern cryptography.

The best factorization algorithms are also complicated, and the easiest option is probably to use a library that someone else has already written. A quick search turned up https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/ which is written in C, and can even make use of a GPU to speed up the search.

It uses the [General number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (GNFS) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Let run some numbers
Square root is up to 10^20
If you only do odd then (10^20/2)
Let assume you can do 100,000 / second
10^(20-5)/2 = 10^15/2
10^15/2 seconds = 15,854,896 **years**
Only processing primes would cut that by a factor of 10
Lets assume you can do a billion a second and only do primes - that gets it down to 0.8 years
This is just not reasonable

At 100,000 / second what could you do in 1 minute?
60,000,000 calcs in one minutes
100,000,000 is 5,761,455 primes
(10^8)^2 = 10^16
Much beyond 10^16 this get unreasonable unless you go after some massive computer power

Why do you need to find a divisor for number that big anyway?

Comment: This is not an answer. You more or less tell the original poster that what he wants is useless and almost impossible. That is not an answer, since it is not impossible and it is not useless.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis If it is not impossible then post an answer on how to do it.    And just what is the use of knowing if a number > 10^38 is divisible?  If you think running the numbers so show it is not practical is useless then that is you problem.

Comment: It is not an answer, do you agree with that? You are telling that what the original poster wants is impossible and useless. That may be a comment, but not an answer. It is possible, as the other answers show (you should read a bit more about factorization instead of pulling off those remarks), and the fact that the largest prime number is not 30 or 40 digits, but more than 22 million digits. It was possible to prove there was no trivial divisor for that. The brute force way, as you describe, is indeed the wrong one. Does it make sense? Yes, finding factors is pretty useful in e.g. decryption.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Impractical is not the same as impossible.  Did not say it was useless - asked why.  And three in the second calculation used primes.

Comment: The fact you mention it getting unreasonable means you think it is impossible for the OP, assuming he does not have massive computer power available. Well, doing that way, it probably would be impossible. And again, this should be a comment, not an answer. Your conclusion is wrong, it does not help and it does not answer the question in any way. It is actually misleading.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What is unreasonable is your interpretation of some simple language.  Really, "getting unreasonable means you think it is impossible"?  Let it go.

Comment: I think you should let it go and delete your "answer", which isn't one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Gee you had not been clear on that before. No